# Null Reference Exception despite checking for Null

Tags: nullreferenceexception

I'm reading from an XML file with C# that has a dynamically generated number of nodes named Col1, Col2, etc. When I attempt to run a while loop on these nodes and check for null I still get a NullReferenceException. Can anyone suggest on how to handle this to avoid the exception?

```
int col = 1;
string colCount = col.ToString();
colCount = "Col" + colCount;
while (nodes[0][colCount].InnerText != null)
{
   timeToFillValues.Add(double.Parse(nodes[0][colCount].InnerText));
   col++;
   colCount = "Col" + col.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is `timeToFillValues` initialized to a value? Or is it `null`?

Comment: timeToFillValues is initialized: var timeToFillValues = new List<double>();

But the NullReferenceException occurs at the beginning of the while loop: while (nodes[0][colCount].InnerText != null)

Comment: And where do you get an exception? Is it inside the loop or when checking condition in the loop?

Comment: The exception occurs when checking the condition, exactly at the while statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned in comments the error happens when checking condition, there are only few cases where you should be getting an error:

```
if(nodes == null)
{
    // was nodes not populated? Then populate it
}
if(nodes[0][colCount] == null)
{
    // does element actually exist or is it null?
}
```

Check for these conditions before calling the while loop and you should find out wha tis causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you dotnetom. Looking at your solution I realized that the exception was occurring because I was calling the InnerText method on an object that didn't exist. The revised while loop: while (nodes[0][colCount] != null)